# Mongoose MongoDB Connection From EC2 Timeout

Tags: mongodb, amazon-web-services, express, mongoose, amazon-ec2

I have a node app that I built locally which connects to my mongodb using mongoose. When I run this locally on my home machine it works fine, I can connect to mongdb and retrieve and save data correctly.

I deployed the same code onto my aws EC2 instance and I get the following error (after 20 seconds):

```
(node:38641) DeprecationWarning: current Server Discovery and Monitoring engine is deprecated, and will be removed in a future version. To use the new Server Discover and Monitoring engine, pass option { useUnifiedTopology: true } to the MongoClient constructor.
/var/www/myapp/html/api/node_modules/mongoose/lib/helpers/promiseOrCallback.js:19
            throw error;
            ^

MongoNetworkError: failed to connect to server [cluster0-shard-00-01-kfxq0.mongodb.net:27017] on first connect [MongoNetworkTimeoutError: connection 4 to cluster0-shard-00-01-kfxq0.mongodb.net:27017 timed out]
    at Pool.<anonymous> (/var/www/myapp/html/api/node_modules/mongodb/lib/core/topologies/server.js:438:11)
    at Pool.emit (events.js:198:13)
    at createConnection (/var/www/myapp/html/api/node_modules/mongodb/lib/core/connection/pool.js:562:14)
    at connect (/var/www/myapp/html/api/node_modules/mongodb/lib/core/connection/pool.js:1009:9)
    at callback (/var/www/myapp/html/api/node_modules/mongodb/lib/core/connection/connect.js:75:5)
    at conn.command (/var/www/myapp/html/api/node_modules/mongodb/lib/core/connection/connect.js:101:9)
    at _callback (/var/www/myapp/html/api/node_modules/mongodb/lib/core/connection/connection.js:329:7)
    at Connection.errorHandler (/var/www/myapp/html/api/node_modules/mongodb/lib/core/connection/connection.js:344:7)
    at Object.onceWrapper (events.js:286:20)
    at Connection.emit (events.js:198:13)
    at TLSSocket.<anonymous> (/var/www/myapp/html/api/node_modules/mongodb/lib/core/connection/connection.js:419:10)
    at Object.onceWrapper (events.js:286:20)
    at TLSSocket.emit (events.js:198:13)
    at TLSSocket.Socket._onTimeout (net.js:443:8)
    at ontimeout (timers.js:436:11)
    at tryOnTimeout (timers.js:300:5)
```

I thought maybe it was an issue with the firewall so I allowed all incoming and outgoing traffic to my ec2 instance and it still doesn't work, I get the same error.

I also tried connecting via telnet directly to cluster0-shard-00-01-kfxq0.mongodb.net:27017 and this works.

I don't have whitelisting enabled on my mongodb (i use username/password) so I don't think its that. I really don't know what else to try :(

The code in my node app that connects to the mongodb is this:

```
const express = require('express');
const mongoose = require('mongoose')
const config = require('./config');
const record = require('./models/model_record');

const router = express.Router();

router.get('/', (req, res, next) => {
     mongoose.connect('mongodb+srv://' + config.db_config.user + ':' + config.db_config.pass + '@' + config.db_config.cluster + '/' + config.db_config.db + '?retryWrites=true&w=majority', { useNewUrlParser: true }, (err) => {

        if (err)
            throw err;

        record.find({}, (err, entries) => {
            res.status(200).json(entries);
        })
    })  
});
```

Comment: IP whitelist is orthogonal to authentication and must be configured.

Comment: omg I can't believe I missed that. Thanks